# LIMIT 1 for the top table WITH JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select

I use PHP, MySQL and Zend Framework. I have some simple tables with simple relations.

```
post_category - post (1:1)
post - post_comments (1:M)
```

I need to select last post with comments using 1 query. It is my query for getting all posts:

```
$select = $this->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('p' => 'post'))
->join(array('pc' => 'post_category'), 'pc.id = p.category_id',
   array('category_name' => 'name', 'category_name_key' => 'name_key'))
->joinLeft('post_comment', 'p.id = post_comment.post_id',
   array('comment_id' => 'id', 'created_by', 'comment', 'comment_date_creation' => 'date_creation'))
->order('p.date_creation desc');
```

I can not add `->limit(1)` cause query can returns more than one row. How can I avoid this situation? I not want to create 2 queries.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be reading this wrong, but if I am understanding you correctly you want to get the post and its comments but limit it to the most recent post...

if thats the case why not add a WHERE clause and a subquery first...p.id = (SELECT Max(id) from post)

In theory this should filter it to the latest post entered. The other option is to select on the max datetime if there is such a field.